# Value accuracy remains the same

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn, finetuning

I have used my own build model and also fine-tuned other two model ResNeT50 and VGG16, but val_acc remains the same for them all.

```
import tensorflow as tf
model_1 = Sequential()
model_1.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu',
                  input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model_1.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model_1.add(Dropout(0.3))
model_1.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model_1.add(Flatten())
model_1.add(Dropout(0.3))
model_1.add(BatchNormalization())
model_1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
               optimizer='adam',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
history_1 = model_1.fit(train_gen,
           epochs=3,
           batch_size=32,
           validation_data=(val_gen))
```

Results:

```
CPU Frequency: 2199995000 Hz
Epoch 1/3
13/13 [==============================] - 81s 6s/step - loss: 2.3583 - accuracy: 0.3001 - val_loss: 0.3717 - val_accuracy: 0.1900
Epoch 2/3
13/13 [==============================] - 67s 5s/step - loss: 0.5658 - accuracy: 0.2054 - val_loss: 0.3613 - val_accuracy: 0.1900
Epoch 3/3
```

[image]

VGG16:

```
     VGG = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                                       include_top=False,
                                       input_shape=(224,224,3))
model_2 = Sequential()
model_2.add(VGG)
model_2.add(Flatten())
model_2.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_2.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
               optimizer='adam',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
history_2 = model_2.fit(train_gen,
           epochs=3,
           batch_size=32,
           validation_data=(val_gen))


Epoch 1/3
13/13 [==============================] - 424s 33s/step - loss: 6.8425 - accuracy: 0.2368 - val_loss: 0.6241 - val_accuracy: 0.1900
Epoch 2/3
13/13 [==============================] - 426s 32s/step - loss: 0.5443 - accuracy: 0.1708 - val_loss: 0.5196 - val_accuracy: 0.1900
```

[image]

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: What does your data look like on which you are fitting the model? You seem to be trying to perform binary classification, what is the ratio of the different labels (e.g. 50/50 or 70/30)?

Comment: How long did you train? 3 epochs a way too low. Also for a pretrained model, it makes sense to first train on the pretrained model and later to finetune as in this example https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/keras_pretrained_imagerec_binaryclass.py